# How Symfony 2 Security Bundle registers to Kernel Events

Tags: php, security, symfony

First of all I'm not a Symfony 2 expert, but I'm trying to understand how the symfony SecurityBundle actually works.

I saw in the docs that a basic implementation to a Session could be registering a EventListener to Kernel events.
Then i started looking at the more complex SecurityBundle to understand it, but I can't find any configuration in security.yml or method inside the Bundle that registers to any event.
I know the Bundle works but I would like to understand how it binds to the Request->Response flow to intercept and filter Requests.

Thank in advance...

Comment: Authentication providers are among the more complex features for Symfony 2.  The various services and registrations are done dynamically since they can be different for different firewalls.  Most of the interesting code lives in SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection.  Read through: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html to get an idea of what all is going on.  Fun stuff.  Challenging to master but worth it in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symfony security component has only one kernel listener, of course, on request and as Cerad said in a comment "The various services and registrations are done dynamically since they can be different for different firewalls", basically it's like a custom listener(1) in a kernel listener(2), the definition of kernel listener is in SecurityBundle(3), the magic of creation services from app/config/security.yml is in SecurityExtension(4) of SecurityBundle.

Basically to integrate symfony security in a non symfony project you need to add SecurityBundle in your AppKernel, so the hard part is to have an AppKernel that coexists with other systems.

(1)Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ListenerInterface
(2)Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall
(3)/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Resources/config/security.xml
(4)Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension